# Inno Setup: Uninstall Dll Server

Tags: dll, inno-setup

Greetings,

With my app I install a Dll server for the Windows shell. The server is registered and unregistered properly by Inno by using the flag "regserver".

However if any explorer windows are open the dll is in use and cannot be deteled by Inno. How can I delete the dll automatically and uninstall the app properly?

Regards,
Cosmin

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the `regserver` flag you could use the `uninsrestartdelete` flag for your shell extension. To quote from the Inno Setup help (`[Files]` section):

> When this flag is used and the file is in use at uninstall time, the uninstaller will queue the file to be deleted when the system is restarted, and at the end of the uninstallation process ask the user if he/she wants to restart. This flag can be useful when uninstalling things like shell extensions which cannot be programmatically stopped. Note that administrative privileges are required on Windows NT platforms for this flag to have an effect.